# Postfix smtp for sending only

Tags: linux, debian, postfix, smtp

The web hosting provider of my company have a mail server with a sending limit of 300 mails a month so the idea is keep using the hosting mail for the mail spool but set up a local Debian server with postfix on it only to send. The idea is configure outlook or thunderbird for the users with the hosting server as POP3 but the mails will be send using my local postfix server that have a static IP.

Is that set up possible??? If so, any idea how to do it? I've been searching around but couldn't find anything....

Comment: In your local mail server, don't configure any pop3 or imap, but i think if you send the emails as company hosting mail server from your mail local server, you can be considered as spammer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this without any bigger problem.

The Debian Postfix gives you 5 possible initial configurations after install. One of them is exactly the local networking outgoing SMTP, which you want.

In the mailing softwares are handled the incoming and outgoing mail settings practically total independent, only their menu system shows this as if they belonged together.

---

There is another possibility, which solved your problem, although didn't do it on the way you think. You can also set up google as an outgoing mail server. About google can you find everything about this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was indeed testing with the Debian inital configuration plus some manual changes and I manage to get it running. I created a spf record and the only think left is secure the server a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you could quite easily set up a postfix server to do that, although it might require a little cooperation from your provider, possibly.

Set up your local postfix instance as a backup host for your domain, and ensure that it forwards any mail it might receive (which are likely to just be NDRs and other types of errors) to your primary server. Then set up postfix to only allow SASL authenticated senders, on port 587, and it should work as you want.